# Segmentation fault occurs when printing array in c

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, segmentation-fault, printf

I get a segmentation fault when printing a dynamically allocated array.  I'm not familiar with dynamically allocated arrays so this could be a problem.  My program compiles fine if I comment out the for loop where I'm printing each element of the array.  So I feel like my readText function is fine but I could be wrong.  I've done research before asking this question and I can't find an answer.  I just need to be able to print out each element of the text1 array.  Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ch1, ch2;
    int size1, size2;
    FILE *fh1, *fh2;

    if( argc<3 ) {
        printf("need two file names\n"); return(1);
    }
    if(!(fh1 = fopen(argv[1], "r"))) {
        printf("cannot open %s\n",argv[1]); return(2);
    }
    if(!(fh2 = fopen(argv[2], "r"))) {
        printf("cannot open %s\n",argv[2]); return(3);
    }
    if(argc>3) {
        if(!(fh3 = fopen(argv[3], "w+"))) {
            printf("cannot open %s\n",argv[3]); return(4);
        }
    }
    fseek(fh1, 0, SEEK_END);
    size1 = ftell(fh1);//Getting fh1 size
    fseek(fh1, 0, SEEK_SET);

    fseek(fh2, 0, SEEK_END);
    size2 = ftell(fh2);//Getting fh2 size
    fseek(fh2, 0, SEEK_SET);

    char* readText(int, FILE*);//declaring function
    char *text1 = readText(size1, fh1);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<size1; i++)
      printf("text1[%d] = %s\n", i, text1[i]);
    return 0;
}
char *readText(int size, FILE *fh)//reads file into a dynamically allocated array
{
  char * text = malloc(size * sizeof(char));
  int i=0;
  while(!(feof(fh)))
    {
      fgets(text, size, fh);
      ++i;
    }
  return text;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow isn't here to debug your code for you. Run this under a debugger, and work your way backwards from the point of the crash.

Comment: Thanks for posting your code, but please put a little more description in your question: what problem are you having, what is the result you expect, and [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far? Going through the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) will help us better answer your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text1[i]` is not a string but just a character. `%s` expects a pointer to the start of the string, so you want

```
printf( "text[%d] = %c\n", i, text1[i] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `%s` specifier expects an argument of type `char*`, these lines:

```
for (i=0; i<size1; i++)
    printf("text1[%d] = %s\n", i, text1[i]);
```

treat `text1` as it was an array of strings, i.e. `char* []` or `char**` respectively.

However `text1` is just a `char*` so you can use `%c` to print just a single character:

```
printf("text1[%d] = %c\n", i, text1[i]);
```